# How do I create a window without any frame regardless of user settings?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-2007

I need to write an application that displays two different pictures in two instances of the application. These pictures must look as if they were put side by side on the canvas of the same window but for internal reasons it must be two different applications not a single one. Is there any way to turn off the window frame regardless of what the user's Windows settings are? I still want to retain the title bar and the close/minimize/maximize buttons.

Bonus points if the two (or multiple) windows look and react like a single one to the user.

A Delphi example would be nice but I can probably do with a hint on which flags or whatever to set using Win32 API (no dotNET please).

Comment: If you want the title bar, then you have to live with the border.

Comment: If I were you, I'd re-examine those "internal reasons" that are making the rest of your project more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: Or you can create a dummy title bar and then use the borderless form.

Comment: Such approaches are always going to be fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a Form without side or bottom borders:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    FBorderWidth: Integer;
    FTitleHeight: Integer;
    procedure AppRestored(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WMNCCalcSize(var Message: TWMNCCalcSize); message WM_NCCALCSIZE;
    procedure WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint); message WM_NCPAINT;
  protected
    procedure Resize; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.AppRestored(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Repaint;
end;

procedure TForm1.Resize;
begin
  inherited Resize;
  if FBorderWidth = 0 then
  begin
    FBorderWidth := (Width - ClientWidth) div 2;
    FTitleHeight := Height - ClientHeight - FBorderWidth;
    Application.OnRestore := AppRestored;
  end;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMNCCalcSize(var Message: TWMNCCalcSize);
begin
  inherited;
  with Message.CalcSize_Params^ do
  begin
    Dec(rgrc[0].Left, FBorderWidth);
    Inc(rgrc[0].Right, FBorderWidth);
    Inc(rgrc[0].Bottom, FBorderWidth);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint);
begin
  DeleteObject(Message.RGN);
  Message.RGN := CreateRectRgn(Left, Top, Left + Width, Top + FTitleHeight);
  inherited;
end;
```

[image: Form with only a title border]

Comment: It looks so ugly that I have to give you +1 :) No, of course it's the exact answer to this question.

Comment: @TLama I did already upvote Rob's comment, because this obviously is not the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Since windows with title bars always have borders, your next option is to make a borderless window and then *paint* a title bar at the top of the window yourself. That means handling mouse messages, too. Start with `wm_NCHitTest`. To make a borderless window, override your form's `CreateParams` method and set the `Style` field so there's no border.